# How can I see the number of memberships at a given date in the past?

Tags: civimember

Is there a way to see how many current members you had on a past date?

For example, how many current members of a specific type on December 31st, 2014?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there might be more elegant solutions possible with Reports (?), you can get the count using an advanced search:

1. Select `Search | Advanced Search` from the menu
2. In the `Basic Criteria` section select `Display Results As`: `Memberships`
3. In the `Memberships` section of the search form set `Start Date` to `Choose Date Range` and then set `To` to the date you are interested in (for your example 31/12/2014). Leave the `From` field empty.
4. Also in the `Memberships` section set `End Date` to `Choose Date Range` and then set its `From` to the day after the date you are interested in (for your example 01/01/2015). Leave its `To` field empty.
5. In the `Memberships` section you can also check the type(s) of membership you want to be retrieved.

After you run that search, CiviCRM is displaying the number of results - which is the number of active memberships at that point in time.

---

Next to the number of results it is also listing the search parameters used. For double checking, this is what it shows when I run it:

> 993 Results - Memberships
>
> Start Date - less than or equal to "31. December 2014 11:59"
>
> ...AND...
>
> End Date - greater than or equal to "1. January 2015 12:00"

---

## Explanation

This search is filtering memberships that started any time before (`Start Date` `To`) 31/12/2014 and did not end before 01/01/2015 (`End Date` `From`).

If you are using the memberships in a way that is correctly updating the Start and End date of the memberships, this should return the correct results.

Comment: Would it be right to say this does not count lifetime members since their Member record has no End Date?