# What's the best way to take a 'snapshot' of membership counts at a point in time?

Tags: civimember, civisualize

I want to create a graph of current membership counts at various intervals - weekly, biweekly, monthly, annual. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is a tricky one - see these questions for a variety of approaches:

http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/is-it-possible-to-get-point-in-time-membership-data

http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/how-can-i-see-the-number-of-memberships-at-a-given-date-in-the-past

http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/membership-status-report/

Comment: Andrew, thanks so much. Checking those out.I did not find them when searching previously. partly because I didn't search for 'point in time'/'point-in-time'. Please add your comment as an Answer and I'll give you the points for it :).

Comment: How do we get this baked into the Civi data model so it can be accurately reported on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky one - see these questions for a variety of approaches:

[Is it possible to get point-in-time membership data?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/is-it-possible-to-get-point-in-time-membership-data)

[How can I see the number of memberships at a given date in the past?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/how-can-i-see-the-number-of-memberships-at-a-given-date-in-the-past)

[Membership Status Report](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/membership-status-report/)